# NPE in putAttribute when invoking tiles

Tags: apache, tomcat, struts2, tiles

I am trying to learn Struts2 f/w with tiles integration but while implementing i am getting NPE in putAttributeTag.

After i click signin i need to move to home page, but i am getting exception while opening home page.

Following is some relevant piece of code.

struts.xml

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="dispatcher" class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult" default="true"/>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"></result-type>
    </result-types>


    <action name="signin" class="actions.SigninAction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="tiles">home</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

tiles.xml

```
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value=""></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/header.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="leftmenu" value="/leftmenu.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/footer.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="rightmenu" value="/rightmenu.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="content" value=""></put-attribute>
    </definition>

    <definition name="home" extends="baseLayout">
        <put-attribute name="content" value="/home.jsp"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Home"></put-attribute>
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

baselayout (other divs for other part of templates are also defined but i have not included them here, if they are needed i will update baselayout)

```
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true"></tiles:insertAttribute>
</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="leftmenu" class=".leftmenu">
            <b>Add New</b><br> Update<br> Search<br> Remove
        </div>

        <div id="content" class=".content">
            <tiles:putAttribute name="content"></tiles:putAttribute>
        </div>
```

`home.jsp` contains simple one line text only.
`actions.SigninAction` returns `success` only (input validation are not incorporated yet, I have checked also this Action returns success).

Logs

Message:

```
ServletException including path '/baseLayout.jsp'.
ServletException including path '/baseLayout.jsp'.
```

Stacktrace

```
org.apache.tiles.TilesException: ServletException including path '/baseLayout.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:614)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:246)
    org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult.doExecute(TilesResult.java:105)
```

and

```
org.apache.tiles.util.TilesIOException: ServletException including path '/baseLayout.jsp'.
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.wrapServletException(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:298)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:200)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:179)
    org.apache.tiles.context.TilesRequestContextWrapper.dispatch(TilesRequestContextWrapper.java:72)
```

and

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.PutAttributeTag.execute(PutAttributeTag.java:204)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    org.apache.jsp.baseLayout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005fputAttribute_005f0(baseLayout_jsp.java:188)
    org.apache.jsp.baseLayout_jsp._jspService(baseLayout_jsp.java:129)
```

It would be nice if you would point out my mistake(s).

Comment: I resolved the issue by making several changes. There was n number of mistakes i was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for NPE was that in `baseLayout`, i was using `putAttribute` tag instead of `insertAttribute`.

```
<div id="content" class=".content">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="content"></tiles:putAttribute>
</div>
```

When this `putAttribute` would have been evaluated, then, `value` parameter was missing. Hence, resulting in throwing a NPE.

Fix:
use `insertAttribute` tag as we will be fetching the value and inserting it into the `baselayout`.

Also some other things i changed after going though [this blog](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-tiles-plugin-tutorial-with-example-in-eclipse/) are as follows:

1. Name of the Jsp's start with Captial letter.
2. In tiles definition, `.tiles` is used as marker for tiles definition from other view technology.
3. Also, a slash `/` is incorporated before tiles definition name, and `struts.xml` is adjusted accordingly.